# Detecting # from keydown event in IE

Tags: jquery

I was able to idenfity the (#) through **e.keyCode** when i used keyPress event but mobile version of IE(Lumia) doesn't support keypress. So i was forced to use keydown instead but the value of e.keyCode is 51 for both (3) as well as (#) when used in keydown.

Is there a way to identify through keydown if user intended to input (#) or (3)?
I want to preventDefault the event if user tries to enter (#).

Also e.key is '3' for both (3) and (#).

Comment: shift key status doesn't work here either,
e.shiftKey is always false

Comment: What do charCode and which return?

Comment: Try to store all keys in an array. When user press button 3, check if the previous key code was 16 (shift). But, instead of checking keys, check the whole string with regex. Dont forget handle copy / paste.

Comment: char code -> 0 for any input

Comment: i cant use input event to check regex because if i change the value of field in input function the change event doesn't trigger in IE.